Can't build a dynamic link on nuxt 3
I need to create a link like this for password-reset
http://localhost:3000/password-reset/d866f5fa974450aabc5fe0943d7266c6659f43e28f1a7a3cda94957374e55974?email=ospreystudio2020@gmail.com
I compiled my link like this
psges--|
       |--password-reset--|
                          |--_token.vue

my _token.vue
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { useRoute, useRouter } from 'vue-router'
import axios from 'axios'

const form = ref({
  email: '',
  token: '',
  password: '',
  password_confirmation: ''
})


const errors = ref([])
const message = ref('')

const route = useRoute()
const router = useRouter()

onMounted(() => {
  form.value.email = route.query.email || ''
  form.value.token = route.params.token || ''
})

Tell me where did I miss something?
Gives error 404

Rename the page-component as [token].vue instead of _token.vue

Ginger Thanks a lot

In the nuxt project, you have to write [].vue for making any dynamic link
Also if you want to make
for your case >>  pages >> password-reset >> [token].vue
